# How to write a database query in asp.net mvc3 to get a record?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I have a query?
I want to retrieve an table's record's data and want to check it with an field.
I know SQL query for it.

```
 string data = select Designation from EmployeeTab where EmpName=name;
```

Here Designation is the field in which some job names are there
EmployeeTab is my table name
EmpName is the name of field and name is a variable in which a session value is there containing an employee name

I want to write this query in asp.net mvc3
can any one tell me what should I write to get value in asp.net mvc3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending @Sagar patel 's reply, You can use something like

```
using(YourEntityname context=new YourEntityname())
{
     var val=context.Users.Where(p=>p.EmpName==name).Select(u=>u.Designation);
}
```

Comment: Hey thnx for the query....

Answer (score 2):

you can do this using ADO.NET Entity framework as follow

```
using(YourEntityname context=new YourEntityname())
{
   var val = from u in context.EmployeeTab
             where u.EmpName == name
             select u.Designation;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have ADO.NET Entity framework

```
 using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
            {
                cn.Open(); 
                string des="";   
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Designation from EmployeeTab where EmpName=name;", cn);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    des = dr["Designation"].ToString() 
                }
                dr.Close();
                cn.Close();
            }
```